# Confusion about front end framework

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I have a question if we don't use any front end framework like angular or react so can we stick with node express or mongodb please answer my question i am very confused about it please help me

Comment: use angular or react for UI development , if no UI dont use them

Comment: These components all have very different uses. It's not clear what you mean - you wouldn't swap Angular for MongoDB, for instance - one's a UI component, the second is a storage system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs is a server side framework .
If you stick with it for front end as well , you can use jade , ejs or other server side languages for serving front end or html as well.

But this will degrade site speed because you are going to server things from server which means you are going to refresh full page and you are not going to use the concept of **Single Page App**

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a code-related question, but I'll answer it anyway.

You can definitely stick with node/express/mongoDB for an application without using a front-end framework.

That's actually what people used to do before SPAs (single-page applications) became commonplace. In PHP, for example, it was common for you to hit a URL, then the URL params were used to make the DB query, and render the right info on the page and then display the page.

What you'll end up doing is making the user navigate the express routes from page to page and serving the rendered html directly from node.

That said, I highly recommend using a front-end framework. It makes the entire experience more dynamic and flexible, and also will reduce a lot of overhead JS-wise.

Hope that helps!